# Using tomcat-native (homebrew) with eclipse (Java 11) on Apple M1 Pro

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, tomcat9

This is my first posting here. I am using a new Apple M1 Pro and I installed Eclipse, java 11 from amazon, tomcat 9 and tomcat-native via homebrew.

My configuration of tomcat works fine, but I want to add tomcat-native to use SSL.

I installed tomcat-native via homebrew to this directory:
`/opt/homebrew/opt/tomcat-native/lib/` which links to `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/tomcat-native/2.0.2/lib`

Then I added in the eclipse configuration the JVM-Parameter:
`-Djava.library.path=/opt/homebrew/opt/tomcat-native/lib/`

When I start the tomcat service via eclipse tomcat plugin (version 9.1.4) I get the following exception:

> WARNING: The Apache Tomcat Native library failed to load. The error reported was [no tcnative-2 in java.library.path: [/opt/homebrew/opt/tomcat-native/lib/]]
> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no tcnative-2 in java.library.path: [/opt/homebrew/opt/tomcat-native/lib/]

I used this configuration on my "older" macbook and it works. Has someone an idea, so that we can solve my problem?

regards
Florian

Notes:
I tried to reinstall all components, update the components, change to another newest eclipse version, search for the failure, but didn't found any solution, especially on Mac M1 Pro.

Comment: Is tomcat-native in homebrew actually compiled for aarch64? Is the version of Java you're using to run tomcat-native also aarch64? They'd need to match.

Comment: =) Tomcat-native ist compiled in aarch64. But I installed the wrong coretto. After I installed the version aarch64 the tomcat native is working perfect. so thank you for your support!